# Returning a numeric value on either side of a dash in a string?

Tags: string, vba, character

Does anyone know how to return only the numeric value immediately on either side of a dash in a string?

For example, let's say we have the following string "Text, 2-78, 88-100, 101". I'm looking for a way to identify a dash and then return one of the numbers (left or right).

Ultimately I would like to check to see if a given number, let's say 75, falls within any of the ranges noted in the string. Ideally it would see that 75 falls within "2-78".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools->References and check "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5." Then you can do something like this. (I know this isn't good code, but it's the idea...) Also, this finds all the #-# patterns and prints either the left or right number for all of them (based on whether the boolean "left" is true or false).

```
Dim str, res As String
str = "Text, 2-78, 88-100, 101"
Dim left As Boolean
left = False

Dim re1 As New RegExp
re1.Pattern = "\d+-\d+"
re1.Global = True

Dim m, n As Match
For Each m In re1.Execute(str)
    Dim re2 As New RegExp
    re2.Global = False

    If left Then
        re2.Pattern = "\d+"
    Else
        re2.Pattern = "-\d+"
    End If

    For Each n In re2.Execute(m.Value)
        res = n.Value
        If Not left Then
            res = Mid(res, 2, Len(str))
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox res
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many different ways with VBA.  Using the Split() function to convert into an array, first using the commas as a delimiter and then using the dash would probably be a way to go.

That said, if you want a quick and dirty way to do this with excel ( from which you could record a macro ) here is what you can do.

Paste your target string into a cell.
Run Text to Columns on it, using the comma as your deliminator.
Copy the row your now have and Paste-Transpose onto a new sheet.
Run Text to Columns again on your transposed column, this time with the dash as your deliminator.
You now have side by side columns of your numbers, which you can compare to your target values as needed.

You may need to use the Trim() functions in there somewhere to remove whitespace, but hopefully the text to columns would leave you with numbers instead of text numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I think there are lots of ways you *could* approach this sort of problem.  It looks like a good way to try and use RegExp.  RegExp is not my speciality but I do like to try and use it to answer some Q's here on SO.  This code has been tested for your example data and is working properly.

Something like this, assuming your text is in cell `A1`, and you're testing a value like `75`, this also captures single digits in your string in the match collection:

```
Sub TestRegExp
Dim m As Match
Dim testValue As Long
Dim rangeArray As Variant

testValue = 75  'or whatever value you're trying to find

pattern = "[\d]+[-][\d]+\b|[\d]+"
Set re = New RegExp

re.pattern = pattern
re.Global = True
re.IgnoreCase = True 'doesn't really matter since you're looking for numbers

Set allMatches = re.Execute([A1])

For Each m In allMatches

    rangeArray = Split(m, "-")
    Select Case UBound(rangeArray)
        Case 0
            If testValue = rangeArray(0) Then
                msg = testValue & " = " & m
            Else:
                msg = testValue & " NOT " & m
            End If
        Case 1
            If testValue >= CLng(rangeArray(0)) And testValue <= CLng(rangeArray(1)) Then
                msg = testValue & " is within range: " & m
            Else:
                msg = testValue & " is not within range: " & m
            End If
        Case Else
    End Select

    MsgBox msg, vbInformation


Next


End Sub
```